# checking the element in the list whether it is there or not in java

Tags: java, java-8

I'm getting the values from the form data like a list

values[,"sample"] and sometimes like this values["test","sample] I want to check whether the first is having any value or not how to check that one

Comment: test.get(0).isEmpty()

Comment: Do you mean 
does it exist as a null value?
or does it exist at all?
or is the String an empty String (which is a value btw)?

Comment: how to check whether it is empty or not

Comment: I have a situation where I'm getting the values from the form like [,"sample"] this. and sometimes like this ["test","sample] now i want to check whether the first index is containing any value or not

Answer (score 0):

First we check that the list itself:

- is not `null`
- is not empty (has at least one value)

Then we look at first element of the list and check, whether value:

- is not `null`
- is not blank (blank values are `""` (empty), "  ", "\t  " (whitespaces)

If you consider values consisting only from whitespaces e.g. `" "`, `"   "`, or `"  \t    "`, you have to modify the example to not use `String#isBlank()` rather than `String#isEmpty()`.

```
public static boolean hasFirstElementNonBlank(List<String> list) {
    return isNotEmpty(list) && isNotBlank(list.get(0));
}

private static boolean isNotEmpty(List<String> list) {
    return list != null && list.size() > 0;
}

private static boolean isNotBlank(String string) {
    return string != null && !string.isBlank();
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> emptyList = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(emptyList + ": " + hasFirstElementNonBlank(emptyList));

    List<String> nonEmpty = Arrays.asList("test","sample");
    System.out.println(nonEmpty + ": " + hasFirstElementNonBlank(nonEmpty));

    List<String> firstEmpty = Arrays.asList("","sample");
    System.out.println(firstEmpty + ": " + hasFirstElementNonBlank(firstEmpty));

    List<String> firstWhitespaces = Arrays.asList("   ","sample");
    System.out.println(firstWhitespaces + ": " + hasFirstElementNonBlank(firstWhitespaces));

    List<String> firstNull = Arrays.asList(null, "sample");
    System.out.println(firstNull + ": " + hasFirstElementNonBlank(firstNull));
}
```

Note: `String#isBlank()` has been added in Java 11 (example won't work for pre-11 Java.